# Angular 2 - ng generate gives invalid blueprint: component error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to generate an Angular 2 component using Angular cli v.1.0.0 - rc1:
"ng g сomponent my-component"
but it gives me an error "invalid blueprint: component". 
Same for router as well, how do I have/get this blueprint for the purpose?

Comment: What's the command you executed to generate the component and is there a component name duplicated in your command?

Comment: I'm using this command:
"ng g сomponent my-component"
No duplicated names in my app.

Comment: It's working for me. My version is rc2. Check whether all the global dependencies meet the requirement to the cli. And upgrading to rc2 might solve the issue

Comment: OK, got ya.
"Check whether all the global dependencies meet the requirement to the cli." - which ones?
""@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1" to "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2", right?

Comment: Yes. node version is greater than 6.9.* and cli global version is updated as the steps given in their doc

Comment: managed to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I've changhed all the @angular dependencies from "@angular/*": "^2.4.0" to "@angular/*": "^2.4.7". So now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1.The generated component has its own directory. Example: 
ng generate component foldername/myComnent
*foldename will be make in arc/app

if you don't want this way please use '--flat' together

2.I changed to use carmel case like below and it seam ok.
ng g сomponent myPomponent --flat

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W4RI.png)